# search contents in an "arxml" file and display them in search view

Tags: eclipse

I have added my own search page to existing search dialogue of eclipse(which opens when ctrl+H is pressed) using  org.eclipse.search.searchPages extension

```
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.search.searchPages">
      <page
            class="search.wizards.MySearchPage"
            icon="icons/my-logo.png"
            id="Search.page1"
            label="My Search"
            tabPosition="1">
      </page>
   </extension>
```

but now I am struggling to search contents in an "arxml" file and display them in search view according to the pattern selected by the user(through the search dialogue page, when search button is pressed)..Please help me with sample code to do this. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Mr.Greg I seek your help..